# Setting body direction of mails sent via phpmailer

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

I use a right to left language. When I send emails from my PHP script using phpmailer, the message body will be received (for example on my account of yahoo) left to right. Although I am using HTML message body and I've set the html tag direction right to left.

```
<html dir="rtl">
```

What can I do to overcome this issue?

Comment: Most likely this has nothing to do with php or phpmailer, but with the way the client interprets (visualizes) that email message. Since all information for that should be present in the HTML markup you post the way _how_ you send that content should not matter.

Comment: Depending on how you create your email (are you using tables?) - anyway, you might have to set the `rtl`attribute on each element containing rtl-text.

Comment: For this situations, you should use inline-styles

Comment: Yes I am using a table, this is correct. I will try and see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML markup in Email Clients has to be supported by the Email Clients. If you are familiar with how differently IE and Firefox can display the same HTML, you will understand the chasm between different "browsers".  Each email client is, yet another browser.

There are [many articles](http://www.pinpointe.com/blog/email-campaign-html-and-css-support), that [discuss the markup](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/) that is [allowed including this stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800028/text-direction-and-alignment-in-email-sent-via-email-php).

That last one seems to indicate that the following will work:

```
<body style="text-align:right; direction:rtl;">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Your tip was very useful